# Calculate total time for the steps counted in the pedometer code in android

Tags: android, pedometer

I am able to show the steps taken using pedometer code but I want to show the total time  taken for those steps too.

Comment: Please show your code what you have done.

Comment: I am using the code from below link.  https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer.

Comment: are u still looking for this... i have a solution for u

Comment: @jafarbtech I need solution for this. Would you kindly provide this?

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to make it as a walking session oriented. because it will count whenever a user steps. so u have to save the current time when the user steps first or when he clicks start walking session button
and you can get the last stepping time from initializing the current time in a global variable in 
**StepDisplayer -> onStep**
get the difference between these times to get the total duration